# Shouldn't this jQuery code return all inputs inside #product-create-2?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this HTML:

```
<fieldset style="display: block;" title="Producto" class="fstep" id="product-create-step-2">
    <section>
        <div class="p_name">
            <input type="text" maxlength="50" required="required" name="product[name]" id="product_name">
        </div>
        <div class="p_description">
            <textarea required="required" name="product[description]" id="product_description"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="p_age">
            <input type="text" value="0" name="product[age_limit]" id="product_age_limit">
        </div>
    </section>
</fieldset>
```

And I'm trying to show a alert for each element with `required="required"` with empty values so I made this:

```
$('#product-create-step-2 > input[required="required"]').each(function() {
    if (!$.trim(this.value).length) {
        alert($(this).prev('label').text() + ' can't be empty!!!');
        valid = false;
    }
});
```

If I leave `#product_name` or `#product_description` empty it never shows a alert and I can't find what I miss, any advice?

Comment: you need to escape "can't" or wrap the outer with double quotes. can\'t or " can't..."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`>` is for selecting **direct descendants**.

You want this instead:

```
$('#product-create-step-2 input[required="required"]')
```

Which will find all matching inputs inside `#product-create-step-2`, no matter how deeply nested.

Also, this will cause a syntax error:

```
' can't be empty!!!'
```

You need to escape the single quote or switch up your quotes:

```
' can\'t be empty!!!'
```

or (my preference):

```
"can't be empty"
```

Comment: Excellent, what about check `textarea` type in the same selector?

Comment: See the [`:input` selector](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/), which "basically selects all form controls".

Comment: Thanks, I've changed to this `$('#product-create-step-' + step + ' :input[required="required"]').each(function() {
            if (!$.trim(this.value).length) {
                alert($(this).prev('label').text() + ' can not be empty');
                $(this).focus();
                valid = false;
            }
        });` but `$(this).focus()` goes always to the latest input, how I set the focus to the first one that cause the validation fail?

Comment: You can `return false;` if you find a blank entry to stop iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Your elements are not direct children of `#product-create-step-2` so you should not include `>`.  Simply have a space between the two selectors and you will get all elements anywhere within the `#product-create-step-2`.

```
$('#product-create-step-2 input[required="required"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have **no inputs** directly underneath the 1st selector.

Try changing your selector to:

```
$('#product-create-step-2 > section > div > input[required="required"]')
```

Or even just

```
$('#product-create-step-2 input[required="required"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

No, look at the DOM more closely, the query should be:

```
$('#product-create-step-2 input[required="required"]').each ...
```

or:

```
$('#product-create-step-2 > section > div > input[required="required"]').each ...
```

since the `>` selects elements that are direct children of the parent.